# How to find mysql duplicates in two mirrored columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mirror

In a MySQL db I have rows. For example:

```
Varchar1    | Varchar2    
XXXXXXXXXX   YYYYYYYYYY   
YYYYYYYYYY   XXXXXXXXXX 
XXXXXXXXXX   CCCCCCCCCC
YYYYYYYYYY   AAAAAAAAAA
CCCCCCCCCC   AAAAAAAAAA
```

How to can i find (and remove) duplikates in row 1 and 2?

One line (1 or 2) should not be deleted.

Comment: why are row 1 and row 2  duplicates?

Comment: Give the real example plz... if id is not relevant, give the primary key of your table or an unique index that allows to distinct between rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.
i have add BIGINT value with bitwise AND of hash of varchar1 and varchar2.

`ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN hex1 BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN hex2 BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN hex BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
    UPDATE t1 SET 
    hex1 = CONV(SUBSTRING(CAST(SHA(varchar1) AS CHAR), 1, 16), 16, 10),
    hex2 = CONV(SUBSTRING(CAST(SHA(varchar2) AS CHAR), 1, 16), 16, 10),
    hex = hex1&hex2;
    ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN hex1;
    ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN hex2;`

and group by hex column

`SELECT t1.* GROUP BY hex;`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.varchar1,t1.varchar2,t2.id, t2.varchar1,t2.varchar2
from yourtable t1, yourtable t2
where t1.id<>t2.id and t1.varchar1=t2.varchar2
```

Try this and come back if doesn't work :)

If this retrieves data you want, then the delete is quite easy :

```
DELETE from yourtable WHERE id in( SELECT t1.id from yourtable t1, yourtable t2
    where t1.id<>t2.id and t1.varchar1=t2.varchar2)
```

Warning : use DELETE only if you are not in production environment or if you are sure of what you are doing or if you are inside a transaction (BEGIN...)

Comment: sorry. id is only for examle. This field is not relevant. Two major fields are Varchar1 and Varchar2. If I'm doing something like `HEX(Varchar1) & HEX(Varchar2) as _hash`. Should be work?

Comment: your solution is not quite right. In the case I delete lines 3 and 4, which I would not.